# How to implement Nested namespacing in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requires

I have been reading some articles and video tutorials to get started with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org). 
Currently I'm reading Addy Osmani's [Backbone Fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals). This [section on namespacing](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#namespacing) suggests YUI-like nested namespacing but as I'm new to BB, I want some help with code.

My actual question is how to implement nested namespacing in **backbone** with **requirejs** (with an example please).

Sincere regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty basic example from my app.js, which is loaded after the requirejs.config in main.js via require(['app']). I create my namespace here, by simply adding an object to the window (and, ok, it does not check for existance, but it is a one-page-app and therefore loaded only once). From here, window.App is available globally, from all controllers and views.

```
define([
        'config',
        'jquery',
        'backbone',
        'router',
        'i18n!nls/strings'
    ],
    function(config, $, Backbone, Router, i18n) {
        'use strict';

        // Create App namespace
        window.App = {};

        // Set translations
        window.App.i18n = i18n;

        // Assign the router
        window.App.router = new Router();
    }
);
```

Comment: I cameaccross this link http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#naming_convention and your answer 
looks good to me, thanks

Comment: I have a question though, whats the `config` after `jquery` you are loading?
is it for app configuration like baseUrl etc?

Comment: Exactly, it is where I set up configurations like urls, keys and similar stuff. It is in my boilerplate although not used here.